# Factors effecting __DIR__ in PHP

Tags: php

I was migrating a server and causes issues with **DIR** in PHP. I am not a developer.

The values of **DIR** in two servers was different. I have created a test.php file in both the server as

```
<?php
echo 'DIR:' .__DIR__;
?>
```

in the directory /var/www-beta/. But one Output shows as DIR:/var/xxx.yyy.com/releases/20130917190718/webroot and other shows as /var/www-beta/ . How to get same value in both the server?

Update : Still cannot find out the solution

Comment: Can you please clarify? I don't understand the problem...

Comment: This is because the paths to your web root is different on each server. The output you see if correct. And it should be ok that the values are different.

Comment: Why do you *want* the file path to be different if your web roots are different?

Comment: If you have any symlinks on the servers, perhaps wrapping your __DIR__ in a call to [realpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: The path to both the servers are /var/www-beta/ .

Answer (score 0):

From php
***DIR**

The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)*

This is the way the function works. The rest is you being confused about which folder you are in.

Answer (score 0):

**_*DIR*_** is Magic constant that returns current directory location which may be different for both servers.

first check document root using following code in both server

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: It doesn't outputs anything